# Calculate $\int_0^{\infty}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1+y)^{-m}dy$

Tags: integration, beta-function

Calculate $\int_0^{\infty}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1+y)^{-m}dy$

This looks like a $\beta $ distribution to me, however I'm unsure of how to approach the distribution when we have $1+y$ instead of $1-y$, my attempt.

Generalising $-1/2$ for $-n$

$$\begin{align}I(-n,-m)&=\int_0^{\infty}y^{-n}(1+y)^{-m}dy \\  &\implies du = -ny^{-(n+1)}, v = \frac{(1+y)^{1-m}}{1-m} \\ &= \left(\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{y^{-n}(1+y)^{1-m}}{1-m}\right) + \frac{n}{1-m}I(-(n+1), 1-m) \\ &= \frac{n!}{(1-m)!(m-n)!}I(0, m-n) \\ &\implies I(0,k)_{k=m-n}=\frac{1}{n-m+1} \\ &\implies I(-n,-m)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n-m+2)}  \end{align}$$

However, when I plug in $n=1/2$ I do not get the expected answer that should be the LHS $$\frac{\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(m-\frac{1}{2})} \ne \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-m+2)}$$

Comment: Why $(1-y)^{-m}$ and not $(1+y)^{-m}$? With $+$ it already is a representation of the Beta-function.

Comment: See http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3 When you integrated by parts, what happened with the evaluation at the lower limit $y=0$?

Comment: @Diger Sorry, still checking through for errors

Comment: @Diger The usual integral definition of the Beta function requires $\;1-y\;$ and not $\;1+y\;$ ...and the integral between 0 and 1

Comment: @Gary thanks for showing me this! I will keep this in memory for next time.

Comment: it's related to the **beta prime** distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $\;y=-1+\frac1t=\frac{1-t}t\implies dy=-\frac{dt}{t^2}\;$ and the integral becomes

$$-\int_1^0\frac{dt}{t^2}\frac{(1-t)^{-1/2}}{t^{-1/2}}t^m=\int_0^1t^{m-3/2}(1-t)^{-1/2} dt=B\left(m-\frac12\,,\,\frac12\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(m-\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(m\right)}$$

Maybe I made a mistake or maybe it is yours, but it is the LHS of your answer upside down....Check this.

Comment: I had a constant $k$ that I did not include, so $k$ would produce my result. Thanks for showing me this! how did you know to make the substitution $y = -1 + \frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: @teslajohn As follows: your integral looked a lot like a Beta Function, so I figured out a substitution to get an integral from zero to $\;1\;$ first ... and it then came around pretty nicely, as a Beta function exaclty (I thought I'll have to make a further substitution...)

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! this has helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

We have that your integral is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{y^{-1/2}}{(1+y)^m}\,dy =\beta(1/2, m-1/2)=\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(m-1/2)}{\Gamma(m)}.$$
Using the Legendre duplication formula, you find that this expression is equal to
$$\pi\,{2m \choose m}2^{-2m}\frac{m}{2m-1}$$
valid for $m>1/2$.